# Understanding the faster multiplication hardware in riscv

Tags: computer-architecture, parallel-computing, multiplication

I found a one question I wonder, but there is something to be clear about.

The link is https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56488/parallel-multiplication-hardware/56518#56518

Q1. In his answer about the question, how can I make a 16 LSB bits by the time I get to the input of the fifth tier.

I think 1 bit before the first tier, and 1 bit after the first tier.

And 2 bits after second, 4 bits after thrid, 8 bits after forth tier.

Suppose multiplying 32 bits and 32 bits

```
Before first tier Mplier0*Mcand[31:0] <- One LSB (Mplier0*Mcand[0])
```

Q2. Then the rightmost ALU in first tier is adding `Mplier1*Mcand[31:0] + Mplier0*Mcand[31:1]` or just two 32bits adding?

(rip off LSB or NOT?)

Q2+. Then the adding would be `Mplier1*Mcand[31:0] + Mplier0*Mcand[31:1]` or `Mplier1*Mcand[31:0] + Mplier0*Mcand[31:1][0 in 0th digit]`

(match the digit length with appending 0 in the end or NOT?)

Q3. In answer context I'm confused about the "Shifted sum of the low-order partial products."

`By the time you get to the last (fifth) tier, you're adding together a 48-bit number (the sum of the high-order partial products) and a 32-bit number (the shifted sum of the low-order partial products).`

I try to reply on the original Q, but it says I need the reputation score.

Sorry about scrolling the original question.

Comment: We prefer that you ask only one question per post.

Comment: `I'm confused about …` is not an [answerable question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (`thrid` and `forth` are misspelled - do you use a spelling checker?)

Comment: (Q2+: `Mplier1*Mcand[31:0] + [0 in MSB]Mplier0*Mcand[31:1]` - "prepend" a 0.)

Comment: I'm doing with 8bits numbers and don't know how to calculate correctly. So I asked the method of doing with parallel adders. What I said confused is before input of the next tier how digits are aligned in calculation.